# Is it best practice to avoid 'self' instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

If I were to implement a class, such as:

```
class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def size(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.current = self.head

        while self.current != None:
            self.current = self.current.get_next()
            self.count += 1

        return self.count
```

The `size` method would work perfectly fine without using `self.` for the `count` and `current` variables, so I was wondering:

1. Why is it the case that `count` and `current` work both with and without `self.`, whereas `self.head` wouldn't work without it?
2. Is it generally bad practice to use `self.` in cases where it isn't necessarily required?

Comment: You're getting it wrong. `self.count = 0` would **create an instance attribute**, named `count` (valid till the instance is destroyed or the attribute deleted), while `count = 0`, would create a local variable (which would be destroyed when exiting method). In this case using `self` is unnecessary, because you don't need those 2 variables outside the method.

Comment: I agree with you @CristiFati, but where did the OP say that using `self` _wouldn't_ create an instance attribute? I think he understands that using `self` will create an instance attribute, hence he's asking _when_ he should and shouldn't use `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using self object you are attaching those variable with the class object, where it can accessible throughout the class.

If self is omitted then the scope of those variable in only inside the size function.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a difference between using and not using `self.` here.

If you use `self.`, you are actually adding a `count` and a `current` attribute to whatever object you are calling `size` on.

If you don't use `self.`, you are defining local variables called `count` and `current` in the `size` method.

This means that if you have `self.`, you can do something like this:

```
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.size()
print(my_list.count)
```

If you don't use `self.`. The above will produce an error saying that `count` is not an attribute.

The reason why `head` needs `self.` is because `head` is an instance attribute as you wrote in the `__init__`. And obviously you want to use the `head` of the current instance when you are calculating the size of the linked list. That's why you refer to it as `self.head`. Just `head` would refer to a local variable, which is not defined.

As to your question of whether it is good to use `self.` in this case. I would say no, since the nature of `count` and `current` seems to just be helper variables that you use to calculate the size, and it does not make sense to make them an attribute of the `LinkedList` class.

Answer (score 0):

1. To put it simply, the reason one must use `self` to reference the `head` variable, is because `head` is an *instance attribute*. In other words, a `head` attribute is created for each instance of `LinkedList`, and to access that `head` attribute internal, one must use `self`.
2. Yes, it would be bad practice to use `self` unnecessarily. `self` should only be used to reference or create instance attributes. Simply creating instance attributes where normal local variables would suffice is unnecessary and perhaps inefficient if `size` is called many times.